# Как прикрутить Poco к QtCreator?

Tags: qt, c++, visual-studio

Сабственно, сабж. Никак не получается скомпилировать пример *genrsakey*. Файл проекта такой:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt
TARGET = genrsakey

DEPENDPATH += src

DESTDIR = ./bin

SOURCES += genrsakey.cpp

CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
    MOC_DIR = ./build/debug
    RCC_DIR =  ./build/debug
    OBJECTS_DIR =  ./build/debug
} else {
    MOC_DIR = ./build/release
    RCC_DIR =  ./build/release
    OBJECTS_DIR =  ./build/release
}

INCLUDEPATH += D:/Programming/Poco/Foundation/include \
    D:/Programming/Poco/Util/include \
    D:/Programming/Poco/Crypto/include \
    D:/Programming/Poco/XML/include \
    C:/OpenSSL/include

LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL/lib/VC \
     -LD:/Programming/Poco/lib \
     -lPocoUtil \
     -lPocoFoundation \
     -lPocoCrypto \
     -lPocoXML \
     -llibeay32md \
     -lssleay32md

win32:LIBS += -lws2_32 \
     -liphlpapi \
     -lkernel32 \
     -ladvapi32

win32:DEFINES += WIN32 \
    _WINDOWS \
    WINVER=0x0500 \
    NDEBUG
```

Компилирую студией 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, необходимо добавить в параметры компилятора:

```
win32-msvc*:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /Zc:wchar_t
```

По умолчанию он выключен.